# Linux FIle Compression

Tags: linux, filesystems

Has anyone used a Linux FS that supports transparent compression?  We'd like to mount a partition where all files are compressed and access them through standard POSIX APIs.  I know there is an add-on kernel module that extends ext3.  Are there other/better options?

Answer (score 2):

ZFS on Fuse. Supports compression on the fly.
 Drawback - runs on userland.

Also, you can patch kernel to include zfs support.

Comment: I think you meant "compression", not "encryption". :-)

Comment: Great feedback.  ZFS looks real.  We are playing with it now.  will let you know what we conclude.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Kristaps says, ZFS does support it.

Your other option is Reiser4, but honestly I wouldn't use that nowadays. It never made it into the mainline kernel. I'm not sure what distros support it or whether it has a future.

Unfortunately, according Wikipedia's [comparison of file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Allocation_and_layout_policies), those are pretty much the only options as far as normal file systems go.

Answer (score 0):

If you go the FUSE way as suggested by Kristaps, you could also use [FuseCompress](http://miio.net/wordpress/projects/fusecompress/). You won't need ZFS support to use it (you might actually use it with any filesystem afaik), but it will still be running in userland.